# Finding the longest Collatz Chain

Tags: c, collatz

I am currently on my Uni homework and this is the last task. Its the 14th euler problem.
https://projecteuler.net/problem=14

So I am really new and i know that have a lot of crappy implementations. When executing this there is actually no output at all. I've been running this for 3 Minutes because i thought it needed to "load"..

My Task is to have a working function that calculates the Length and then take this length and compare it to have the longest chain as the "Final" output.

I tried to have a Loop that calculates the length for every i in 1000000 and then save this number into an array with the same size.

At the end of the Loop I want to compare the last length with the current and save the longer into the var if its longer.

I am stuck for like the past 2 hours

Here is my current Code:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <math.h>
int number = 1000000;
long sequence = 0;
int seqLen = 0;
int startingNum = 0;
int currLen = 0;

unsigned calculateCollatzLength(unsigned n){
    
    int ans = 1;
    while (n != 1) {
        if (n & 1) {
            n = 3 * n + 1;
        } else {
            n >>= 1;
        }
        ans ++;
    }
    currLen = ans;
    return currLen;
}


int main() {
    int cache[number];

    
    for(int i = 0; i <= number; i++){
        
        calculateCollatzLength(i);
        
        cache[i] = currLen;
        
        if (cache[i] > seqLen) {
        seqLen = cache[i];
        startingNum = i;
            
       
        
        }
        
    }
    
    
     printf("The Longest Collatz Chain from 1 to 1000000 is %d long and has the starting number %d \n", seqLen, startingNum);
  }
```

Hope that this is kind of understandable to ask in on this since this is my 3rd Question and it kind of feels like cheating asking but i dont know who to ask or cant find any answers :(

Comment: There are two problems with `int cache[number]; ... cache[i] = currLen;` (a) because the array might overflow the stack and (b) because `cache[1000000]` is exceeding the array bounds.

Comment: You don't even need an array or to store each result.

Comment: Crucially, starting at `0` will iterate forever, because an even number is halved.

Comment: @WeatherVane Oh, could I just store it in a var maybe? And then check it all?

Comment: You only need `seqLen` and `currLen`. You don't need to store the length of each sequence.

Comment: @WeatherVane Oh my god. I just changed it it to two and it works now lol

Comment: "It works" is lucky, since you still have the array bounds problem.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thanks for the advice, I am trying to change it now as you mentioned!

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i <= number; i++)` <— replace `<=` with `<` to avoid accessing `cache` out-of-bounds

Comment: Have fun! Please don't overlook that the *raison d'être* for Project Euler is to introduce mathematical concepts, not to teach coding.

Comment: 5 global variables is 5 global variables too many. Shoot for zero.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a cleaned-up working version of your code. There's no need for a cache, and `int64_t` is a safer bet than `unsigned` (which is likely to be 32 bits) to avoid overflows. Your use of global variables was confusing and unnecessary – you can simply return the length of the sequence and                                                         find the maximum in `main`.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdint.h>

int collatz(int64_t n){    
    int len = 1;
    while (n != 1) {
        if (n & 1) {
            n = 3 * n + 1;
        } else {
            n >>= 1;
        }
        len++;
    }
    return len;
}

#define N 1000000

int main(void) {
    int longest_i = 0;
    int longest = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i <= N; i++){
        int len = collatz(i);
        if (len > longest) {
            longest_i = i;
            longest = len;
        }
    }
    printf("**collatz(%d) = %d\n", longest_i, longest);
  }
```